# Bootstrap Datetimepicker cannot set the date value

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker in my project. And I'm facing the problem with setting the date value after my input control rendered.

At first I set up the datetimepicker as follow:

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment(),
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}).on('keypress paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

And then I load the actual data date value of the control by calling below function:

```
function SetDate(control,date)
{
    $('#'+ control).datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(date)
    });
}
```

And then the datetimepicker show only current date but it return correct date value that is not current date when I fetch the value with document.getElementById('elementname').value.

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, for the options showed, that you are using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker

The way you are using the picker is wrong, because what you are doing is calling again the picker, better do it this way:

```
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker();
```

And then with your control/function (I will use a button triggering the action)

```
$('#set').on('click', function() {
  SetDate("myDatepicker", moment().subtract(1, 'day'));
});

function SetDate(control, date) {
  $('#' + control).data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate(date);
}
```

Where `.data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate(date)` is what set the defaultDate for later.

And where `moment().subtract(1, 'day'))` is taking out one day and is the parameter `date`, and is not necesary to parse out again as is a moment object; 
If you need to parse a string date you could use:

`moment('20170202','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Where first parameter is your date string.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Here how the options are set for the plugin http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Answer (score -1):

Fetch the value using the following :

```
$("#elementname").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Thanks for advise! but my problem is not fetching value. The problem is about defaultDate. Even though I set the default date but it always showing current date that I set when setting up datepicker and not showing the set date. Moreover the datepicker keep showing current date even I select other date value. By the way, I'm using React.js and consider the environment as virtual DOM. Thanks heap for your kind advise.